# How to display a message below the dropdownlist not an alert box when specific dropdownlist item is chosen?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, autopostback

To provide consistency, I cannot use an alert box to display a message in my code when someone chooses a specific item in a dropdownlist. It needs to display a red message below the dropdown field only if someone has chosen a specific item.

So in this case if someone chooses Alabama from a state dropdownlist for example, a red message needs to display below the dropdownlist box immediately after the choice is made. The old version of this form works accurately, but the new version of the form with many changes in it is not displaying this message.

In the code behind file (the aspx.vb file) I have these code snippets:

```
Protected Sub StateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StateDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged
    If StateDropDownList.Text = "AK" Then
        AlabamaPanel.Visible = True
        Session("Alabama") = "Yes"
    Else
        AlabamaPanel.Visible = False
        Session("Alabama") = "No"
    End If
            StateDropDownList.Focus()
End Sub
```

I'm using previous code with certain edits and another part of the problem is that I don't understand the Session("Alabama") part - I don't find anywhere else in the code where Session("Alabama") is listed or rather to understand what Session() is and how it even would know what an Alabama Session is... So if you know something about Session() that might be helpful - I see this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) but that's not helping me understand. The only place in the code that Alabama by itself exists is in the items of the dropdownlist. And maybe that is part of the problem since in the old code the Alabama was specifically noted in a long list like (in the aspx file, not the aspx.vb file) such:

```html
<asp:DropDownList class="DropDowns" ID="StateDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AL">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AK">Alaska</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AZ">Arizona</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AR">Arkansas</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CA">California</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CO">Colorado</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CT">Connecticut</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="DE">Delaware</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="DC">District of Columbia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="FL">Florida</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="GA">Georgia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="HI">Hawai'i</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ID">Idaho</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="IL">Illinois</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="IN">Indiana</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="IA">Iowa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="KS">Kansas</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="KY">Kentucky</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="LA">Louisiana</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ME">Maine</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MD">Maryland</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MA">Massachusetts</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MI">Michigan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MN">Minnesota</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MS">Mississippi</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MO">Missouri</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MT">Montana</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NE">Nebraska</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NV">Nevada</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NH">New Hampshire</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NJ">New Jersey</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NM">New Mexico</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NY">New York</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NC">North Carolina</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ND">North Dakota</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="OH">Ohio</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="OK">Oklahoma</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="OR">Oregon</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="PA">Pennsylvania</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="RI">Rhode Island</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="SC">South Carolina</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="SD">South Dakota</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TN">Tennessee</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TX">Texas</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="UT">Utah</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="VT">Vermont</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="VA">Virgina</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="WA">Washington</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="WV">West Virgina</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="WI">Wisconsin</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="WY">Wyoming</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

But now we are calling to another VB file to grab the state dropdown list and the full set as shown above is no longer in the code.

Since there is nowhere besides this list that no longer exists or this list that does exist in the separate vb file we are calling to which is successfully populating the dropdownlist, then that could perhaps be blocking the Session() from working?

In the new code (in the aspx file, not the aspx.vb file), all of the above is replaced with:

```html
<label for="StateDropDownList">State <span class="Required">*</span></label>
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="StateDropDownList" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm trying to use (in the aspx file) :

```html
<asp:Panel ID="AlabamaPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3">

            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="AlabamaLabel" runat="server" visibile="false" Text="Alabama Text that I want to appear right below the statedropdownlist field if they choose alabama."
                Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#e00022" />

        </td>
    </tr>
</asp:Panel>
```

to get the text to show up on the page below the dropdown field if the user chooses Alabama and it's simply not displaying. I have also tried putting the long list of states back in instead of calling out to the separate dropdowns vb file.

I'm also trying to use Update Panel, wrapping the dropdown list with an

```html
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" 
     UpdateMode="Conditional"
     runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>

       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And that has benefited me because before that I wasn't able to include the autopostback="true" without it taking me to a blank screen whenever someone chose Alabama from the dropdown list. Now at least the entire screen isn't blanking out... But still I'm not getting the message to show on the screen.

Also I've tried this, but still no message appearing:

```html
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="StateDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="StateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Any ideas or is anything glaringly obvious as to why my message isn't showing up when someone chooses Alabama?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also, please watch your indentation - we actually have to _read_ this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updtPnl">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="StateDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="StateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Al">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Other value</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="AlabamaLabel" runat="server" visibile="false" Text=""
    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#e00022" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And change the code-behind as:

```
Protected Sub StateDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StateDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged
If StateDropDownList.SelectedValue = "Al" Then
    AlabamaLabel.Text = StateDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text + " is selected!"
    AlabamaLabel.Visible = True
Else
    AlabamaLabel.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original code that you provided you have the following issues:

1) you are looking at the text of the Dropdown for an abbreviation, which is not the text in the dropdown that is the value so you would need to use something like StateDropDownList.SelectedValue = "AK"

2) The AlabamaPanel gets set to visible however; you do not set the visibility of the label to true, so the panel is visible, but has no controls in it that are visible.